# Incrementally ascending hash codes in a collection of objects

Tags: java, collections, hashcode

Hi guys : I'm trying to scan through some objects to see if there are any repeats.  To do this, Im using the hashCode field.  The objects are serialized in a binary file.

It looks like this :

hashCode=26594
hashCode=26595
hashCode=26596
...

I would never expect that hashCodes from a collection would exhibit such  a pattern unless the JVM or thrift creates hashCodes on the fly for some objects, in certain instances (or maybe, each object created internally has a hashCode that is set to a statically incremented value).

Of course, this question has no definite answer at this point - but, in general, is there a reason or a common case where a stream of objects would have incrementally increasing hashCodes ?  Maybe if there is a scenario where somebody has seen such a phenomenon in the past, it might help me shed light on the binary file which I'm trying to understand.

- Minor detail : these objects are binary serialized using the Apache thrift library, and they are read/written in java/hadoop, entirely.

Comment: Where were they serialized from? If they were in a sorted collection it's only natural that they are ordered. As for the value: hashcodes are computed from object data, nothing to do with generation order.

Comment: I think it depends on how the `hashCode` method is defined for the objects?

Comment: You already gave the most likely reason; the hashcode is an incremental ID. Thrift can take a hashcode generation strategy (IIRC), too. Not sure how Hadoop would deal with it.

Comment: Why would a sorted collection have incremental hashCodes ?  I didn't know that compareTo() had any relation to the hashCode() .

Comment: I've been reading some thrift pages and it seems that the Java generator has a `hashcode` option to generate quality hashcodes.

Comment: Also there are a couple of issues in Jira about it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-68 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-628

Comment: LOL, seems that actually that thrift thing might override hashcode and provide a very bad quality hash unless you tell the generator to use a "high quality" one. If it were true, I totally agree with this post: http://www.codesmell.org/blog/2009/08/thrift-or-where-generated-java-source-code-sucks/

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check for duplicates you should use the `equals` method instead of `hashCode`. If you read the javadoc for `Object.hashCode`, it says:

> *It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.*

This means that you can have two Objects o1 and o2 with the same hashCode value but where `o1.equals(o2) = false`. You'll be detecting a false duplicate.

To check for duplicates you can use a Set, and check for each added object if `Set.add(object) == true`. If it returns false, it means that it was already in the set.

The incremental hash in your description seems to me a very bad hash function, unless all the objects are the same class and are there's also an incremental relation between them. For instance, run this code:

```
    List l1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
    for (Object object : l1) {
        System.out.println("hashCode: " + object.hashCode());
    }
```

You are not saying if the objects are your own defined classes not. If they were yours, always remember that if you override `equals`, you should always override `hashCode` as well. If not, you are violating the `hashCode` contract and some classes (like the hashed collections) may not behave as you'd expect.

Comment: I agree with almost everything you said.  However, I don't think the incremental hash is "very bad".  There are no collisions, and, based on the limited info presented, the lower bits vary.  It's just hard to imagine how this hash was generated for "random" objects.  My guess is that the objects are not random, i.e. for some reason the collection has a bunch of successive integers, or, more likely, as OP and @Dave Newton pointed out, the hashcode function provided by thrift did something "unusual".

Comment: Well, theoretically, each class has the responsability of defining the hashcode or using the superclass one.

Comment: Agreed.  The idea that thrift (or anybody) provides a "hashcode generation strategy" was news to me and slightly disturbing.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a reason or a common case where a stream of objects would have incrementally increasing hashCodes ? Maybe if there is a scenario where somebody has seen such a phenomenon in the past, it might help me shed light on the binary file which I'm trying to understand.

The short answer is that it is interesting but certainly not wrong.  The object's class in question is generating the `hashCode()` -- it is nothing to do with the serialization unless for some reason the hashcode value has been calculated during object construction which *would* be much more bizarre.

You have to remember that the hashcode is typically used with a mod function to place a value in a hash-bucket.  As long as the value returned by the `hashCode()` method obeys the specs, it is fine:

- the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer for the same object value, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified
- If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result
- the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

It may be that it is using some sort of database ID that was generated and are monotonically increasing on purpose.  Or this is some sort of Hadoop pattern to track unique results or something.

Answer (score 1):

Could they be a sequence of numbers?

Looking at the code for Integer and Long, their hash codes are essentially that number and consecutive numbers will pretty much have consecutive hash codes.

Note that Long will only be consecutive up to Integer.MAX_VALUE, after that it is not as consecutive, though still well patterned.